# What is the best background color to conserve battery life?

Tags: mobile, colors

I'm developing a web based mobile application and I was thinking about the default background color.

Do different color backgrounds use different amounts of battery life? For the best battery life should I choose black or white or some other color?

I would assume that because there's a back light behind the LCD then white would use the least amount of power because no pixels would have to be turned on, is this assumption correct?

Comment: i'm not a professional in hardware but I'd agree that white would be best.

Comment: A further question that I would be interested in seeing answered is "What is the impact of screen color (in extreme cases) to battery life?"

Comment: I just read yesterday, that AMOLED displays (used e.g. in the Nexus One) don't use any energy for black pixels.

Comment: Using my old LCD monitors and plugging them into a power meter, I discovered that white is indeed more efficient than black by maybe 10% for my monitors

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For most devices the background colour you use has no effect on the battery usage. The backlight intensity isn't changed.

However on AMOLED displays the power consumption can vary "significantly". See the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_LED#Power_consumption) for details:

> "For example, our measurement shows that a commercial QVGA OLED display consumes 3 and 0.7 Watts showing black text on a white background and white text on a black background, respectively."

Answer (score 4):

With ordinary LCD displays, the back light will consume far more power than any number of pixels. If your device has fixed brightness, you can pick any color you want, the difference in power usage will be miniscule.

On the other hand, if you *can* adjust the brightness, then what you want is the color scheme that gives the best contrast/visibility at the lowest possible screen brightness.

If it's an embedded device and you're in total control of features like screen brightness, this might be worth investing a little time. But if you're writing an app to run in an existing OS framework, something like overall display brightness probably won't be something you will be allowed to control.

Comment: Is that any known color combinations for low brightness system?

Answer (score 1):

For LED displays the background color does not matter.

For AMOLED displays, which are used in many of the newer smartphones, a black background saves a significant amount of energy.

If battery life is the only concern, use a black background.

Answer (score 0):

Latest research confirms that lighter backgrounds use more energy

[Microsoft blog on battery conservation](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/01/17/optimizing-battery-consumption-of-windows-phone-applications/)